# After disabling weak ssh ciphers I cannot ssh in at all

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security

My goal is to disable weak ssh ciphers on a linux machine (specifically Lubuntu 14.10--yes, old, there are hardware compatibility reasons that it cannot be changed right now).

First thing, I checked that I can indeed ssh into the machine with a variety of ciphers. For example `ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-cbc` and `ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-ctr` prompt me for my password and let me in.

I've added the following to the bottom of my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

```
# Cryptographic Policy
# See https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/sshd_config#cryptographic-policy
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr  
HostKeyAlgorithms ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss  
KexAlgorithms ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256  
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
```

Now I'd like these changes to take effect, and I read everywhere that I should restart the sshd service. I assume that this must be the service that listens for ssh connections or something like that. I don't seem to have one running, though. It's not in the list of services. When I try and restart I get this:

```
$ service sshd restart
sshd: unrecognized service
```

So, I just rebooted the machine.

Even without this service running, the lines I added are doing something because after updating the config file and rebooting I am unable to ssh in at all using any cipher. It refuses the connection instead of giving me the anticipated "no matching ciphers found" (for a cipher that is supposedly disabled, now).

```
$ ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-cbc
ssh: connect to host <IP REDACTED> port 22: Connection refused
$ ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-ctr
ssh: connect to host <IP REDACTED> port 22: Connection refused
```

If I remove those lines and reboot, I can ssh in again as before.

It seems to me like adding these lines to the sshd_config file are breaking ssh. The fact that I cannot restart sshd potentially because it is not even running is odd. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what it is I am doing. Or, could the issue be that I'm using this old version?

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-8, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Thanks in advance for your insight. I hope what I've written is clear, and certainly I am happy to provide more details if needed.

---- UPDATE ----

Thank you for your answers and comments. From these I have figured out that for this machine I should not restart sshd, the service I should restart is called ssh. I was able to restart the service and put the changes made to /etc/ssh/sshd_config into effect by running `sudo service ssh restart`. This is more convenient than rebooting, and as you have all pointed out, less risky.

After restarting ssh I have the same behavior as after rebooting from before: all connections refused. My guess now is that Shadur is right, a typo, or one or more of the ciphers or algorithms I've asked it to use are unaccepted by this version.

---- UPDATE 2 ----
It works if I take out the HostKeyAlgorithms option. It seems like this was not a configuration option for OpenSSH 6.6. I think [this commit](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/3a1638d) may be where it was added.

```
$ ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-cbc
Unable to negotiate with <IP REDACTED> port 22: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
$ ssh USER@HOST -c aes256-ctr           
USER@HOST's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-23-generic i686)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your machine is using `service` and not `systemctl`?  Try typing `systemctl` and see what it spits out.

Comment: FWIW flavors of Ubuntu 14.10 would have used `upstart` rather than `systemd` - see for example [Upstart or Systemd](https://askubuntu.com/a/600333/178692). Even where systemd is the default init, `/usr/sbin/service` is provided as a wrapper script for backward compatibility I think. It might just be a matter of `sshd` being the wrong service name - try `service ssh restart` or `service ssh status` for example.

Comment: "So I just rebooted my machine" -- future advice? Don't do that, especially when you're not sure your remote access will come back up.

Comment: @steeldriver, ah thanks, this output makes more sense now for `service ssh restart` I think I get a rejected stop and start that were forwarded to upstart `stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.56" (uid=1000 pid=4591 comm="stop ssh ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")`. From what I just read, it seems like I can use upstart directlly with `stop ssh` or `start ssh` which both tell me `Unknown job: ssh`.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. It needs to be `sudo service ssh restart` and then I get output saying that ssh was stopped and started.

Answer (score 0):

Your critical mistake was rebooting when you weren't sure the service would come back up, but let's deal with the situation as is.

You mention hardware; I'm hoping this means you have physical access to the machine in a pinch so you can log on to a console.

Once you do (or someone else manages in your stead, if the machine is hosted elsewhere), I'm fairly sure you'll find that the name of the service is `ssh` rather than `sshd`, which means that `service ssh status` should give you an overview like the following:

```
shadur@periapsis:~$ service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-21 21:45:37 CEST; 12h ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 1357 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1362 (sshd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 19080)
     Memory: 7.2M
        CPU: 5.703s
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             ├─ 1362 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 2 of 10-100 startups"
             ├─42848 "sshd: [accepted]"
             ├─42903 "sshd: root [priv]"
             └─42904 "sshd: root [net]"
```

Followed by a number of log entries detailing the last few things the `sshd` process had to say.

Alternately, you can check with `journalctl -u ssh.service` and see what the log output was.

My guess would be that you had a typo somewhere or referenced an encryption method that said older version of ssh doesn't know about.

For future reference, `sshd -t` or `sshd -T` will do a dry-run test of the configuration and spit out errors so that you don't have to risk restarting your sshd process when you're not sure it will come back up.

Comment: I did see ssh in the list of services and tried restarting it as well, but that didn't work. It sounds like I should pursue this. For me `service ssh status` tells me `ssh start/running, process 1099`, but nothing else. `journalctl` tells me `No journal files were found`. Thanks for the `sshd -t` trick. I do have access to this machine another way, but this will come in handy in the future.